# facebook chargeback refund details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

we are dealing with heavy chargebacks and refunds. But I am unable to identify how can I get the details of chargebacks and refunds. We have published our game through third party so they own the Company Account for transactions. We have asked them, but apparently they don't  have anything to help us out. I have used Graph API to log the transaction details and I have also used the debug tool to find out the reason or details of chargebacks and refunds. but even our refunds does not have any reason attached with it. Please help me out of this. I have done alot of Google on this but i am unable to find out what I need to know

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

All you will actually get is a “Refund Reason Code” – which of these there are, and how to access them, is described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/disputes/#refundcb_tracking

Edit:

It does not look like you can look up the refund reason code via the API – but Facebook will send it to you, via a ping to your callback URL:

> “If the order has been refunded by Facebook, **we will ping your callback** with a payments_status_update for the order in questions with a status of refunded. In addition, there will be an additional field returned called refund_reason_code with one of the following values: […]”

So you will have to react to that and evaluate the refund reason code (save it to your database, …) in this callback.

Comment: thanks @CBroe for your response, but I have already explored it and it does not include "refund_reason_code". I am really surprised too. because Facebook API clearly tell that it will show that but for me it is not. perhaps I am missing something. I am using this call:
https://graph.facebook.com/ORDER_ID?status=refunded&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
and i am passing it application access token. but the result that i get does not include "refund_reason_code", though it says the order is refunded. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Thanks, I have just implemented your solution. I have read that part of documentation before, and my understanding is that the facebook will not send the refund_reason_code in the ping call as this parameter is not present in the sample callback format given just under the para you mentioned. But you can get the refund_reason_code along with other details through the POST call as given under the para you mentioned. But as I have already tried POST and it is not working, I think its the right decision to check what you are refering too. lets keep the fingers crossed. I will update you.
thanks

Comment: Hm, the docs are really a little tangled in the description of the callback and the API call. I think now it’s rather the API call that should give you the refund_reason_code – but you have to do a __GET__ request to `/ORDER_ID?status=refunded`, not POST.